# How to prevent hackers to insert to many data into a database

Tags: database

In a context of a web site, that allows the users to create a profile and insert every day some data inside a database, which is the most effective method to prevent hackers to insert to many data into the database using the profile he has created?

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to prevent? Do you mean you want to keep him from signing up multiple times, or?

Comment: With one account you can store your data daily, normaly text and number. I want to prevent someone to generate automatically a large number o data and insert them in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple answer for this. You have to take care of many things. And what you are trying to stop.

1. Duplicate date  , fix : Use duplicate checking
2. Random string , fix : Use filtering and sanitization
3. Robot insertion , fix : Use Captcha , if white listing
4. To many data: Monitor user activity and ban for few minutes his write permission.
5. 

Of course that all will be hard to do if you are not using any framework or any CMS for your website.  But there are many library available out there.

If you are still not clear please ask specifically.

Comment: I want to prevent the point 4 of your list. I don't want to allow to insert to many data intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

You may for example

- use a CAPTCHA to make the person (or the script automaticly posting things) enter some text
- only allow a certain amount of posts per ip-adress per hour (of course: not that secure, becuase ip-adresses could be changed)

There are more things like this (for example checking if the content makes sense, if this is possible) which you could combine. Each new "level" will increase the effort to do evil.